# UIViewPropertyAnimator repeat not working

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` to animate fade in and fade out. Passing repeat option won't repeat the animation and work for only one second.

Am I doing anything wrong?

**Code With Issue:**

```
private func faceFadeAnimator() {
            faceAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear, .repeat], animations: {
                self.animatorImageView.alpha = self.animatorImageView.alpha == 1 ? 0 : 1
            }, completion: { (position) in
            })
        }
```

**WORKAROUND:**

```
private func faceFadeAnimator() {
        faceAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(1000)
            self.animatorImageView.alpha = self.animatorImageView.alpha == 1 ? 0 : 1
        }, completion: { (position) in
        })
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a great workaround. This is a class function which I assume may have adverse effects on any and all other UIView animations that are going on at the same time.

Comment: @user1898712 I haven't checked if it's affecting elsewhere or not but if you can give an answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This repeat bug has been around for years. Looking at the state of UI frameworks, they will probably continue to overlook this.

These will NOT work: `repeat` option and `setAnimationRepeatCount()` (also deprecated)

A workaround solution is to fallback using `Timer` to repeatedly start the animation.